# Is there a Pipelining Monad?

Tags: haskell, monads

So I'm playing with the [Cantor pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Pairing_function&oldid=853876462#Cantor_pairing_function), and trying to follow the wikipedia formulas as close as possible.

```
type N = Int

toCantor   :: (N, N) -> N
fromCantor :: N      -> (N, N)

toCantor (x, y) = (x + y) * (x + y + 1) `div` 2 + y
```

- `type N` so I can easily change to `Integer` later (some of the intermediate calcs will get big).
- uncurried form, partly to follow wp, partly so `(fromCantor . toCantor) === id` and `(toCantor . fromCantor) === id`.

Again following wp:

```
fromCantor z = (x, y)  where
     x = w - y
     y = z - t
     t = (w * w + w) `div` 2
     w = floor $ (sqrt (fromIntegral (z * 8 + 1)) - 1.0) / 2.0
```

This works and everything but gee that formula for `w` is ugly!

- It needs all those parens because I've got a formula nested inside a function call and a loose-binding `(-)` nested inside a tight-binding `(/)`.
- (And both those operators are non-commutative, so I must be careful.)

**Q 1.** Is there a way to make that formula prettier/pointfree?

I see the formula starts from `z` and builds outwards. So I can pipeline the calculation:

```
(.|) :: a -> (a -> b) -> b   -- pipelining
infixl 0 .|
x .| f = f x                 -- aka flip ($)

wP :: N -> N                 -- w with Pipelining
wP z =  z
     .| (* 8)
     .| (+ 1)
     .| fromIntegral
     .| sqrt
     .| subtract 1.0
     .| (/ 2.0)
     .| floor
```

Is this style prior art? Is `(.|)` a good way to spell that operation -- I think I've seen it as a Lens operator(?)

**Q 2.** I've (deliberately) laid that out in pseudo-monad style. Could it actually be a `do` block?

- First I need a monad. I could use `Maybe` or `(Either e)`  -- which would be a Good Thing because several of those functions are partial, and I ought to be using a safe version.
- Then instead of `z` I'd put `return z`.
- But the binding goes the wrong way round. Instead of `Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`, I want `Monad m => m a -> (a -> b) -> m b`. That looks like an `fmap`, but flipped.
- I could apply some sort of lifting to the functions/operators, but that then obscures the arithmetic with monad plumbing.
- Rebindable syntax?

Comment: As an aside, expect to get wrong answers when doing a floating-point square root with numbers too big to fit in Int in a 64-bit build of ghc. It just doesn't have enough precision. Use a proper Integer square root instead.

Comment: Something like `wP = floor . (/ 2) . subtract 1 . sqrt . fromIntegral . succ . (* 8)` would be more traditional if you’re going to use a “pipeline” style.

Comment: Hmm. I'm thinking Unix "pipeline", flowing left to right, each arithmetic operation modifying the value. Prefix style piling up 7 operations gives my head stack overflow. Flowing left-to-right, or rather top-to-bottom, is why I like monad style. I think prefix style for combinators or flow-of-control logic is OK, but I would avoid so many as 7.

Answer (score 2):

Your operator `.|` already exists in `Data.Function` as `&`. To make it pointfree, you can either use `>>>` from `Control.Arrow`, or invert the order of everything and just use `.`. For `Monad m => m a -> (a -> b) -> m b`, you want `<&>`, from `Data.Functor`.

Comment: For these sort of things I almost always use `(>>>)` - it makes the code look much nicer.

Comment: Strange `(&)` doesn't come up on Hoogle. It's `infixl 1`. Compare `infixr 1 (>>>)`, but that's reverse compose rather than reverse func apply. `(<&>)` is in `Functor` not `Monad`, so I can't use `do` block.

Comment: @AntC I'm not really sure what a `do` block would gain you here. This is not a problem that really maps well to `Monad`s. It is essentially just function composition/application. I guess you could name intermediate results but, personally, I think this would make this particular example *less* readable (coming up with names is often hard, especially for things like the intermediate results here). Something to consider: sometimes people try to "force" monads to do something they aren't good at (I have seen people do this on multiple occasions). It is best to try to avoid this.

Comment: Also, for `(>>>)`, it doesn't really matter if that operator associates to the left or to the right since function composition is associative. Association direction does change things for `(&)`, but it is sort of a preference thing in that case. There is the occasional debate about which way is better and each has its conveniences.

Comment: @AntC "`(<&>)` is in `Functor` not `Monad`, so I can't use `do` block." Everything that's a `Monad` is also a `Functor`, so anything that works on `Functor`s also works on `Monad`s, so use of `<&>` does not preclude use of `do`.